# Tag a user when entering a username in a EditText

Tags: android, tags

I want to replicate the functionality of tagging a user while entering his name in edit text after '@' is entered

Please see the attached image what exactly i want to do

[image]

Here sally jones tagged chris remkes while typing his name from an edit text.

Any suggestion how to do this so when that name is clicked i can show the user detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ClickableSpan:

```
SpannableString textString = new SpannableString("Great video @ChrisRemkes I'm making a similar one but I think it could do with some editing like your one!!!");
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The text '@ChrisRemkes' has been clicked. Do something.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        // NOTE: here's where you can set the styling give UI feedback that this is text that can be clicked on. 
        ds.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue));
    }
};
// NOTE: you will need to setup getStartPositionOfTag(textString) and getEndPositionOfTag(textString) to pattern match on the textString to find the start position and end position of @ChrisRemkes
textString.setSpan(clickableSpan, getStartPositionOfTag(textString), getEndPositionOfTag(textString), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(textString);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```